# multiple boolean tests within one method

Tags: java

I have a class with different boolean properties set and the method `test()` checks all these properties and returns a boolean value.

**Which is the fastest way?**

**version 1:**

```
public boolean test(){
if(!test1) return false; 
if(!test2) return false; 
if(!test3) return false; 
if(!test4) return false; 
if(!test5) return false; 
if(!test6) return false; 
if(!test7) return false; 
return true;
}
```

**version 2:**

```
public boolean test(){
    return test1 && test2 && test3 && test4 && test5 && test6 && test7;
}
```

**version 3:**

```
public boolean test(){
        Predicate<Boolean> test1 = c -> getTest1(); 
        Predicate<Boolean> test2 = c -> getTest2(); 
        Predicate<Boolean> test3 = c -> getTest3(); 
        Predicate<Boolean> test4 = c -> getTest4(); 
        Predicate<Boolean> test5 = c -> getTest5(); 
        Predicate<Boolean> test6 = c -> getTest6(); 
        Predicate<Boolean> test7 = c -> getTest7(); 
        return test1.and(test2).and(test3).and(test4).and(test5).and(test6).and(test7).test(true);
        }
```

I would prefer version 1, because it`s the cleanest way, however, which one is the fastest?

Comment: If you really want to find out which is fastest for your specific situation, then [benchmark it yourself](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness).

Comment: This is a nano-optimization that isn't worth the effort.  Performance won't be an issue.  Write the clearest, most readable code you can.  I'd prefer #2: succinct and readable.  The other two are verbose and murky.

Comment: +1 to benchmark, but be aware that it's easy to come up with a test that isn't measuring what you think it's measuring. Also, if your code is already "fast enough", optimization attempts might end up being time spent unnecessarily.

Comment: If I have a lot of boolean properties (test1 till test100) within this test()-method, so I want to look for the fastest..

Comment: @nimo23, 100 boolean properties isn't "a lot". I just did a micro-benchmark of option 2 with 1,000 boolean properties and the code executed in less than a single microsecond.

Comment: @RoadWarrior micro-benchmark must be compared by all of those 3 versions to see which is the fastest when having thousands of booleans .. however, I will stick to version 2 as it is the cleanest way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` fast exits on any false, so it's logically equivalent to 1. 3 will technically be a bit slower because of the lambda construction.

Comment: thanks. yes you are right. 1 and 2 are logically equivalent, however, in version 1 I do an extra step in negating all values..

Answer (score 0):

In your case test 1 and test 2 are the fastest one and i think without a difference because we know that O if is 1 and using && operator is the same.
The 3 example is the slowest one because it use an extra interface using callbacks

Comment: version 1 and 2 has no difference in speed? but I negate all returned values with version 1..

Comment: i think that negate dont have any complexity so i think is the same